# Как получить process id по имени процесса

Tags: c, драйвер

Занимаюсь разработкой собственного драйвера.

Как получить ID процесса, зная только его имя? Нужно именно на C, не C++

OS Windows 7, тип драйвера - внутриядерный.

Comment: Какая операционная система и её версия? Какой тип драйвера — user mode или внутриядерный?

Comment: Windows 7, внутриядерный

Answer (score 1):

Windows Driver API не предоставляет ни способа прямого получения идентификатора процесса (PID) по его имени, ни даже возможности перечисления всех процессов в системе.

Поэтому нам придётся самостоятельно вести ассоциативный массив *«Имя процесса — PID»* и своевременно его обновлять.

Обновление производится с помощью `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`, позволяющего отслеживать создание и уничтожение процессов.

Ассоциативный же массив вы должны использовать свой. Неважно, будет ли он основан на связном списке, группировке по хэшам или чём-то другом, я просто введу некие функции `MAP_ADD` и `MAP_REMOVE` для добавления и удаления элементов соответственно.

Тогда получится примерно следующий код:

- Регистрация перехвата (выполнять в `DriverEntry`):

  ```
  PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine(NotifyRoutine, FALSE);
  ```
- Разрегистрация перехвата (выполнять в `DRIVER_OBJECT::DriverUnload`):

  ```
  PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine(NotifyRoutine, TRUE);
  ```
- Обработка собственно перехвата:

  ```
  static void NotifyRoutine(HANDLE ParentId, HANDLE ProcessId, BOOLEAN Create)
  {
      NTSTATUS Status;

      // Получаем PID из описателя
      PEPROCESS Process;
      Status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(
          ProcessId,
          PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
          PsProcessType,
          PreviousMode,
          (PVOID*)&Process,
          NULL
      );
      if(NT_SUCCESS(Status))
      {
          // Получаем указатель на имя процесса.
          PUNICODE_STRING ProcessName;
          Status = SeLocateProcessImageName(ProcessName, Process);
          if(NT_SUCCESS(Status))
          {
              if(Create == TRUE) // Если создан новый процесс
                  MAP_ADD(ProcessName, ProcessId);
              else // Если процесс уничтожен
                  MAP_REMOVE(ProcessName);
          }

          // Уменьшаем счётчик ссылок на процесс, иначе у пользователя образуется
          // большое количество неубиваемых процессов.
          ObDereferenceObject(Process);
      }
  }
  ```

*Важное замечание: опыта в драйверописательстве не имею, всё вышесказанное получилось в результате изучения MSDN и исходных кодов ReactOS.*

Comment: А если процесс был запущен до запуска драйвера?

Comment: @Виталий, `wininit`, корень иерархии пользовательских процессов, запускается после того, как отработали все `Reinitialize`. Так что ни один пользовательский процесс упущен не будет; насчёт системных же (типа `System`) не знаю.

Comment: Пока разбираюсь, как на низком уровне работает связка `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`/`Process32First`/`Process32Next`, с помощью которой [перебирают процессы в подсистеме Win32](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20874381/2553424). Закончу — опубликую второй ответ.

Comment: Разобрался. Смотрите второй ответ (DDK под рукой нет, проверить работоспособность, опять же, нет возможности).

Answer (score 1):

Готовой функции для получения PID по имени процесса нет, но можно вручную пройтись по связному списку процессов.

```
HANDLE getPidByName(PCUNICODE_STRING name)
{
    NTSTATUS Status;

    // Отладочная метка для области памяти с копией списка процессов. Пусть будет "PrcL"
    // Так как у нас LittleEndian, то первая буква находится в старшем байте.
    #define MEM_TAG ('P' << 24 | 'r' << 16 | 'c' << 8 | 'L')

    // Мы не можем заранее узнать размер буфера, поэтому будем подбирать 
    // экспериментальным путём, увеличивая при каждой неудаче на размер страницы (4КБ).
    // Судя по тому, что так делает даже CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(), это нормальная
    // практика.
    PVOID ProcThrdInfo;
    SIZE_T ProcThrdInfoSize = 0;
    do
    {
        // Буферы размером больше PAGE_SIZE выделяются в отдельных страницах, поэтому
        // фрагментация кучи нам не грозит.
        ProcThrdInfoSize += PAGE_SIZE;
        ProcThrdInfo = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(PagedPool, ProcThrdInfoSize, MEM_TAG);

        if(ProcThrdInfo)
        {
            // Получаем копию списка процессов. Принимающий буфер расположен
            // в пространстве ядра, поэтому вызываем Zw-версию функции, не выполняющую
            // проверок указателей.
            Status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(
                SystemProcessInformation,
                &ProcThrdInfo,
                &ProcThrdInfoSize,
                NULL
            );

            if(!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
                ExFreePoolWithTag(ProcThrdInfo, MEM_TAG);
        }
    } while(ProcThrdInfo && Status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);


    if(ProcThrdInfo)
    {
        if(NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        {
            PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo
                = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)ProcThrdInfo;

            // Перебираем записи, пока не найдём ту, что с искомым именем
            ULONG ProcOffset = 0;
            HANDLE FoundHandle = 0;
            do
            {
                ProcessInfo = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)
                    ((ULONG_PTR)ProcessInfo + ProcOffset);

                if(RtlCompareUnicodeString(ProcessInfo->ImageName, name, FALSE) == 0)
                    FoundHandle = ProcessInfo->UniqueProcessId;

                ProcOffset = ProcessInfo->NextEntryOffset;
            } while(FoundHandle == 0 && ProcOffset != 0)

            ExFreePoolWithTag(ProcThrdInfo, MEM_TAG);
            return FoundHandle;
        }
        else
        {
            // Непредвиденная ошибка у ZwQuerySystemInformation(). См. Status
            // для получения подробной информации.
            return 0;
        }
    else 
    {
        // Не хватило памяти
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Если `ProcessInfo->ImageName` недоступен ([верно начиная с какой-то версии Windows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/040cc8ce-3802-491c-8820-c32eedae5def/systemprocessinformation-has-wrong-declaration-its-right-?forum=vcgeneral)), попробуйте заменить его на троицу *`PsLookupProcessByProcessId()` + `PsGetProcessImageFileName()` + `ObDereferenceObject()`*.

Comment: Ругается на аргументы функции ObReferenceObjectByHandle, хотя соответствующая библиотека подключена
PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION, а ещё 
подключил соответствующую библиотеку, но компилятор ругается на PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION

Comment: @Виталий, какой текст ошибки? И посмотрите, пожалуйста, откуда появилась `ObReferenceObjectByHandle`, ведь в вышеприведённом коде её нет (по крайнем мере в явном виде).